# On restriction to centralizers of all elements in group cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology

If $G$ is a finite group, what do we know of the natural «restriction» map $$H^\bullet(G,\mathbb Z)\to\left(\bigoplus_{g\in G}H^\bullet(Z(g),\mathbb Z)\right)^G,$$
with $Z(g) $ the centralizer of $g $. In particular,  can we describe the kernel and cokernel, or fit it into an exact sequence?

Comment: (the kernel and cokernel can be described using Ext-groups from the aumentation ideal with its adjoint action, but that is rather opaque)

Comment: Are you allowing $g=1$ on the right hand side?  If so, then your map is injective, and the cokernel is isomorphic to the sum of the terms with $g\neq 1$.

It is also worth noting that the right hand side is the cohomology of the free loop space of the classifying space $BG$.

Comment: I meant to sum over conjugacy closed subset, really. I'll fix this when I get hold of a real keyboard.